# How to "tie" 3 RSI-indicators to one Bollinger Band, using IMAonArray()?

Tags: quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

There are 3 RSI indicators, each having its own period.
I want to tie all 3 to one Bollinger Band.
Tell me how to do this better?

```
 for(i=limit; i>=0; i--) {
     ma=iMAOnArray(RSI,0,bb_period,0,0,i);         // midle
     stdev=iStdDevOnArray(RSI,0,bb_period,0,0,i); // dev
     BBUP[i]=ma+bb_dev*stdev;                    // up
     BBDOWN[i]=ma-bb_dev*stdev;                 // down
     Buff4[i]=0;
     Buff5[i]=0;
 }

 if(limit<Bars-1) limit++;
 for(i=limit; i>0; i--) {
      if(PrevSignal >= 0) {
         if(   RSI[i]    <  BBDOWN[i]
            && RSI[i+1]  <  BBUP[i+1]
            && RSI2[i]   <  BBDOWN[i]
            && RSI2[i+1] <  BBUP[i+1]
            && RSI3[i]   <  BBDOWN[i]
            && RSI3[i+1] <  BBUP[i+1]
               ) {
               Buff4[i]  = Low[i]-5*MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_POINT); // MathMin(BBDOWN[i],WPR[i]);  // Low[i]-5*MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_POINT);
               PrevSignal = -1;
         }
      }
 }
```

I want that when all 3 RSI were below BB, then the signal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKff7.jpg  [image]

Comment: Could you clarify, **what have you tried so far**, so as **to "tie" RSI[] with RSI2[] and RSI3[] together to one BBand**, to meet your expected outputs? Syntax is marginal, when missing the goal. Thanks to edit your post to reflect this missing aspect and to define The Target, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check 3 RSI values against the Bollinger Bands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132346/how-to-check-3-rsi-values-against-the-bollinger-bands)

Answer (score 1):

### The code AS-IS could be designed with 4x less overhead:

Even before O/P will define the target ( how to tie three values into one ), one might have already detected the code-blocks are sync-stepped / aligned in `[i]`-indexing, not peeking into the future, non-intervening each to the other's values ( princially indeendent ) and thus redundant, so one could safely save a lot from these "shared" overheads:

```
int    i;
double ma,
       stdev;
for(i=limit; i>=0; i--) { RSI[ i] = iRSI( Symbol(), Period(), rsi_period,   PRICE_CLOSE, i );
                          RSI2[i] = iRSI( Symbol(), Period(), rsi_period_2, PRICE_CLOSE, i );
                          RSI3[i] = iRSI( Symbol(), Period(), rsi_period_3, PRICE_CLOSE, i );

                       /* the "last" for(){...} code-block body is not included,
                          until the calculus of how to tie three vectors
                          into a common Bollinger Band is defined by O/P,
                          but
                          could fit in this common "stream"-processing too
                          */

                          }
```

<sub>The O/P code has been remarkably **[changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44102558/revisions)** - may check the revisions</sub>

---

### Nota bene: ad-hoc the presented update

Given the Quantitative Finance heritage, from J. Welles Wilder, the author of the said RSI model, the definition says:

> Relative Strength Index (RSI) is a momentum oscillator that measures the speed and change of price movements. **RSI oscillates between zero and 100.**

It turns out, that any attempt to mix apples and oranges leads to just a principal confusion. Taking the apples == the Bollinger Band ( having a clear PriceDOMAIN dimension [CCY2] ) and trying to mix it ( additively, using { ADD | SUB } operations ) with oranges == RSI ( a dimension-less relative / percent indicator ) will yield an uninterpretable result ( has a hidden superposition + scaling uncertainties ).

### Still in doubts?

Just let's take **XAUUSD** for a second. It's Bollinger Band values, bearing in mind any reasonable multiples of sigma ( StDev ), the RSI will always be under the lower-band ... thus such construct will have **zero information value, as:
`RSI-<0..100> << BollingerBandLOWER-( 1257.000 - ( N * sigma ) )`**

So a model ought be revised, so as to have some Quantitative Finance support built-in. Mixing apples with oranges simply will not help in any serious business sense.

Comment: I need to make 2 bands (up and down) bbands and put 3 RSIs in them ... So that I depending on the settings of RSI to Bbands saw different results. RSI and Bbands in my basement ...

Comment: No need to explain the BB mechanics, it is **the rest, that is not clear**. Given BBaxis == 1.00000, sigma == 0.2, RSI1[0] == x, RSI2[0] == y, RSI3[0] == z, **what would you like to plot with the { x | y | z }-values**, besides the common lines of { 1.20000 | 1.00000 | 0.80000 }-BBands? **Any equation, screenshot or illustration?**